# ListView Control Automation Error - Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, listview, automation, runtime-error, vba

I am trying view data in some range in a locked sheet via a ListView in a UserForm that is displayed when the user double clicks specific cells in another sheet but I am having problem populating the ListView as I get an error from this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer: i = 0

    ListView1.View = lvwReport

    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Clear
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "BOQ_Code", 100
    ListView1.ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Description", 300

    For Each rng In Sheet4.Cells(3, 1).Resize(22, 1) '.Range("A3:A22")
        i = i + 1
        With ListView1
            .ListItems.Add , , rng.Value
            .ListItems(i).SubItems(1) = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value
        End With

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

I am getting this error:

[image: Automation Error]

I tried searching all over the web but I can't find any solution for this.

Comment: `Sheet4.Cells(3, 1).Resize(22, 1)` becomes `$A$3:$A$24` - is that the cause of your error ?

Comment: Also you can put a breakpoint in the sub and comment out the `Application...` statements whilst you are debugging. Have you stepped through this code and can edit your post with the line that the error appears on ?

Comment: The error is a run-time error meaning that after the ListView is populated with a few rows this error is raised, as for the code itself I tried a break point at every possible line. Even worse I tested my code on other machine and surprisingly it worked.

Comment: Using ListView control version 6 seems to be working fine without errors, strange.